# C: Ctl+D exit the program

Tags: c, linked-list, eof

I wrote this function in C:

```
int process_list(node_t *head){
    char c;
    node_t *prev = head; /* Define pointer to point the previous node */
    head->next = NULL;
    head->data = getchar(); /* Insert the first char to the head's data property */
    if ( head->data == EOF ) {
        return head;
    }

    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
        node_t *current = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current->data = c;
        current->next = NULL;
        prev->next = current;
        prev = current;
    }

    print_list(head);

    return 1;
}
```

And I want to check the program, so in-order to simulate EOF I've been told that I need to use ^D (ctrl+D). However, when I use this it just stop the program, and I don't see the input that the `print_list` should display. The result is:
[image]

But the desired result (I simulte this by replace EOF in '\n' and just press enter):[image]

The function `print_list`:

```
void print_list(node_t *head) {
    node_t * current = head;

    printf("The input is:\n");

    while ( current != NULL ) {
        printf("%c", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("\n");

    free_list(head);
}
```

Any idea why EOF terminate the program?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please copy that output and paste it as text in the question? Is it really easier to take a screnshot, crop it, upload it somewhere than doing a simple copy+paste?

Comment: Why? Pictures are much more easier to understand then text

Comment: That is why you don't store the return of `getchar()` in a `char`..............

Comment: It seems like this function works exactly as you'd expect... Ctrl+D is EOF for stdin and you're reading everything until you put EOF in the stdin buffer. If you want to read until newline, try replacing EOF with that.

Comment: but pictures are not searchable or indexable....

Comment: @MichaelWalz the `process_list` function contains `getchar`, I'd say that counts as I/O

Comment: @erip I want to test this as similar to "real life" as possible, the results now are not the results that I am expected, The user don't see what he was typing, As the task requirements

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca right, sorry, deleting this comment

Answer (score 2):

The `while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )` loop is incorrect, since `c` is of type `char`.

`getchar()` returns a value of type `int`, which is either a value that can be represented using an `unsigned char` or `EOF` - which is an implementation  defined value that typically cannot be stored in a `char`.

Change the type of `c` to be `int`, not `char`.

***The following comments are specific to Unix.***

To work as you expect, the CTRL-D needs to be entered by the user at the start of a line (first character input to the program, or immediately after a newline).

If CTRL-D is hit after characters on a line, it needs to be typed TWICE.  The first CTRL-D will cause preceding characters to be read without closing `stdout`, and the next call of `getchar()` will wait for another character. At that point, the second CTRL-D will close `stdout`, typically resulting in `getchar()` returning `EOF`   (and entering something other than CTRL-D will simply mean reading continues).

In your case, since you are only entering one CTRL-D but not at the beginning of a line, the environment (e.g. debugger) in which you are running the program is either timing out or detecting the CTRL-D as well, and causing the program to terminate.  That's only a possibility though - you haven't provided enough information to confirm that.

There is no workaround, other than using a technique for reading keystrokes directly - which is not possible with standard C.   Similarly, there is no means in standard C to force a human user to behave was required.

Comment: Yeah, okay.   You're running into a "feature" of unix - particularly if it is posix compliant.   Clarification added.

Answer (score 0):

Try `while(scanf("%c",&c)!=EOF)`.

This will store the input character to `c` and if you reach `EOF` then `scanf` will return `EOF`; which will break the loop - basically what you tried to do in your code.

Or, an alternate solution can be `while(scanf("%c",&c)==1)` - where the loop will continue as long as `scanf` can successfully read a character, and break when it can't (i.e- when it reaches `EOF`).

### About the question - why `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) terminates the program instead of processing the existing input:

Just like pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the console finishes a line of input (which also adds a `'\n'` character at the end of the input line), or pressing the arrow keys move the cursor in the console (which doesn't add any character in the input), or pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> removes a previous character from cursor's location; when you are entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in the console, you are basically giving the console a command to terminate the program (by giving a signal to the console that the input stream is finished - which we consider as inputting `EOF` in the console). As a result, although you entered some characters in the console - but didn't finish the input line by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (so basically the program hasn't received the input yet), the program terminates before processing the input. To make the program receive and process one line of input, you have to end the input line by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you try to add `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> before ending the line by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the program will terminate without processing that line.

Comment: Nonsense. ^D is processed by the tty-driver and transformed into an EOF *event* anddelivered to the connected program. The parent progam (the shell) still has the access to the (open) connection.